# How to use packages generate by Ecore model - Android?

Tags: android, eclipse-emf-ecore

As a part of my project, I created class diagram using Ecore diagram and generated a model out of it.. I used this tutorial as my reference ..http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html...My question is once I have created the model (in section 4 of this tutorial "Generate Model Code")...how do I use this in my normal android project as like I import other packages in my simple android project..??

In section 6 of this tutorial its using those model in plug-in project..but I want to use that model code in my normal project..I hope u r getting what I am trying to ask..please ask me if u need more detail on this...thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the answer but this bugzilla says it has a port of EMF's runtime for Android:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=296770